# Subview's bottom anchor is relative to superview's top anchor, and not bottom anchor as intended

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a UICollectionView, and within each UICollectionViewCell I have a UILabel that's supposed to be at the bottom of the cell. All of the constraints work correctly except for the constraint that is meant to position the UILabel relative to the bottom of the cell (imagine that the label is 40 points above the bottom of the cell). Instead, my code places it 40 points **below the top of the cell** and as a result the UILabel is at the top of the cell, not the bottom. The code clearly specificies bottom anchor for the cell's contentView, so I'm not sure what's going on.

```
// Constraints work correctly
self.text.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CellConstants.textWidthAnchor).isActive = true
self.text.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CellConstants.textHeightAnchor).isActive = true
self.text.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leftAnchor, constant: CellConstants.textLeftAnchor).isActive = true
// Incorrect constraint 
self.text.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
```

Comment: Do you intentionally not have a constraint on `self.text.topAnchor`? My guess is that's what's causing you trouble.

Comment: @AdamPro13 you are correct! Adding top anchor fixes, and even having top anchor by itself fixes it. Any thoughts on why bottom anchor by itself wouldn't do the trick?